# How to delete data safely

Tags: mysql, database

Let's say we have two table in database  user and order
user and order are one to many relation 
each user can do 0 to n order 
now I need to delete user as they are related in database if i remove user automatically i remove all order done by user at this point my calcule of profit  wil be wrong why because the function of calcul profit do sum of all order in order table (which don't include the delete user orders) 
my qestion is how to delete user but keep information correct

Comment: This is probably more an accounting thing.  Do you hold your profit on a table or do you calculate it at a particular point from the data held.  If you delete one of last financial years orders, how does this affect the profit?

Comment: You have both Java and PHP - not sure which (if any) are relevant.

Comment: This is why, typically, order tables do not have a foreign key to a user table. Instead, user information (name, address, whatever is relevant) is copied there. This is because the order needs to be a snapshot of the data at that stage (a user changing their address should not affect any open orders; same with products changing prices). So it is your premise ("i remove a user so I remove their orders") that is wrong.

Comment: (And it would be helpful to use punctuation and paragraphs when asking a question.)

Answer (score 1):

There are three alternatives.

The first one would be using a transaction when you delete a user, the profit gets auto-calculated.

The other alternative could work is creating a procedure in PL/SQL which triggers an SQL in order to update the profit when a user is removed.

As @krylov123 says, you could add a flag when a user is deleted and auto-calculating the price when the user is not flagged as removed.
Probably this one is the best one.

Comment: Not sure about the `PL/SQL` part.

Comment: in some cases you need to know from where you get that order as we know  (KYC) and anti-money laundering may ask fot the user order information so if there is only 2 way 
1- keep keep data but hide it
2- using a transaction to handle data whene it modifed
i'm asking what should i do in this case

Comment: "All roads lead to Roma". I mean, in the end, you want X and there are different approaches to get it, and sometimes, no one is better than others, just depend on the context. You have to pick which one fits better. In case you pick the soft-delete option, probably you will need to create a cron that checks daily/weekly/whenever if the deleted user whose date is further than X time, if so, remove it completely and then update the products to avoid wrong values.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a flag to the users table, for example `deleted`.

No need to delete the orders, just set `users.deleted` to `true`. Record still persist in database and you can calculate any reports (inc profit).

You will need to handle that flag at the login process and do not allow user to authenticate if `users.deleted = true`.

Comment: I'm working with that alternative right now the problem  is the user always persist in database (it's not legit to informe the users thet there accounts deleted and all all infomration persist in database)

Comment: @SamiBadouz then you can set `orders.user_id` field to NULLable. First set it to null and then delete the user.